# driver.quit(); does not work for FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

`driver.quit();` does not work for FirefoxDriver.

Please see the code snippet I am using:

```
WebDriver wr1;
//launching firefox browser
wr1 = new FirefoxDriver();
Thread.sleep(2000);
//Closing the browser
wr1.quit();
```

Comment: Can you able to view launched Firefox Browser? Think Bowser didn't opened with in 2 Secs. Try increasing sleep time to 15 Seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Please try 
`wr1.close();`
instead of
`wr1.quit();`

Sometimes it can be browser compatiblity issue, try to downgrade Firefox is the solution above doesn't work.

Comment: wr1.close() works but still the console has an error saying - org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.